# UILabel in tableHeaderView is not resizing correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my `tableHeaderView` I have a `UILabel` that is resizing based on its text. With some text it works, with other text it does not.

Not working example: **There's no twelve**

[image]

Working example: **Everything there from one to fifteen**

[image]

Here's the code I use:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.testLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.tableView.frame.width - 30.0
    self.headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
  }

  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    guard self.tableView.tableHeaderView == nil else { return }
    self.headerView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.headerView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    self.headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    var newFrame = self.headerView.frame

    self.headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let newSize = self.headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    newFrame.size.height = newSize.height

    self.tableHeaderHeight = newSize.height
    self.headerView.frame = newFrame
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView
  }
```

Comment: Is your header view contents laid-out with constraints? Seems a little odd to do `self.testLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.tableView.frame.width - 30.0` ... What do you get if you simply comment-out that line?

Comment: Take a look at this article - I just tried it and it seems to work just fine. Even handles size changes (such as device rotation) properly. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/ (note: I am not associated with the site - just found it with searching)